8 to 9 hours night time sleep but extremely cranky in the morning (13mo)
My 13 months old son is not a good sleeper. He wakes up 1-2 times on average during the night and stays in his crib for a maximum of 10 hours, totaling, at best, 9 hours of sleep overall.
He usually wakes up between 6 and 7 AM. We take him to daycare between 8:30 and 9 AM, but almost always, by that time, he already starts showing signs of sleepiness (rubbing his eyes, yawning, and becoming irritable and whiny).
I think he doesn't get enough rest at night, but after trying various adjustments (like going to bed earlier, later, closer to or further from dinner), I can't get him to accept being taken back to sleep if he has already slept at least 9 hours.
What do you think the problem is?

What age is your son? If he is pre-school age, does he take afternoon naps?

I am sorry, you're right, gonna edit the question

9 hours of sleep is simply not enough for a 13 month old, they should be getting closer to 11-12 hours a night plus two naps during the day, for a total of 13 or so hours per day.

That sounds right to me, but we don't seem able to let that work. My son won't accept to be left alone in the bed with us next to him to sing or speak gently, so the only approach he will accept is holding him in my arms and sing lullabies while walking up and down the room. After walking for over half an hour, it's hard to keep going because of his weight... and if he decides he has had enough he will fight my attempts with everything he has...

According to the Pediatric Sleep Council, "Toddlers around 12-months-old sleep, on average, 11 to 14 hours per 24-hour period." Does your child still take naps at daycare?  There are kids who just refuse to sleep a lot and it may seem like there is nothing you can do to make them sleep more.
I have found two things to be important to the sleep quality of my child:  1) level of fatigue and 2) bedtime routine.  Your son may have excess energy if he hasn't had much outdoor playtime during the day.  You may try taking to the park after picking him up from daycare to let him get some more sun and run around.
Also, starting the bedtime routine with a bath, reading and cuddling can help, so he is also mentally ready to fall asleep.  Based on your comment, it sounds like he is accustomed to being lulled to sleep by having you walk around with him, perhaps from his baby days?  Breaking this cycle may require you to be firm to change his bedtime routine so that he learns how to fall asleep on his own.  If he is able to fall asleep on his own, that will probably help him start taking naps at day care as well, resulting in more sleep.

Hey, thanks for you help. Actually, he is perfectly able to take the single afternoon nap they offer at daycare (he is usually able to sleep for a couple of hours there). Also, as far as they tell me, he learned to sleep on his own or with minimal support from them in his own bed there, so it's just a home-related problem. Anyway, overall he gets 10-11 hours per day, so we are on the lower end of the admittable range. Maybe I have simply to accept him as a non long-time sleeper ;-)
